# Excel: How to set list data validation to point to a column in a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range called "items" spanning 3 cols and 10 rows. In another worksheet I have a cell that uses a data validation list to allow a user to select from a drop down. In the source I want to specify the first column of the named "item" range. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your validation range formula to

```
=INDEX(items,0,1)
```

Though is your named range called "item" or "items".... I've assumed "items"

Answer (score 0):

To add to that if your "items" named range is a table - using index(items,0,1) will not work.

You will have to create a new named range called "itemsFix" or something similar and "itemsFix" should refer to "items". Then using

```
=index(itemsFix,0,1)
```

will work.

Making your named range a table is very useful. Every time you add new data to the bottom of that table, the named range will automatically update. If it isn't a table, the named range will never update by itself.